# How to display column headers returned by PostgreSQL function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, set-returning-functions

I have the following PostgreSQL function which returns multiple columns from a table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION userbyid(id integer)
RETURNS TABLE(id int, username character varying(30), email character varying(254), last_login timestamp with time zone) AS
$$
SELECT
    id,
    username,
    email,
    last_login
FROM
    auth_user
WHERE
    id = $1;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

The result it returns looks like this:

```
                        userbyid
--------------------------------------------------------------
(2, smith, smith@example.com, "2017-06-04 19:47:49.472259+00")
```

Is it possible to display the output with the correct column headers, something like this:

```
id         username       email               last_login
--------------------------------------------------------------
2          smith          smith@example.com   2017-06-04
```

I'm looking at the CREATE FUNCTION document page and it isn't clear how to do this.  I've also searched online and haven't seen an article that discusses this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your set returning function in the `FROM` clause

```sql
SELECT * FROM userbyid(1);
```

as opposed to

```sql
SELECT userbyid(1);
```

Here is [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f70473df1aae4112f12e46fc907ea875) demo

Sample output:

```
 id | username |       email       |       last_login
----+----------+-------------------+------------------------
  1 | user1    | user1@example.com | 2017-06-13 12:00:00-04
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to format  PostgreSQL to show the colum headers;
Set it with:

\t

this can be seen in PSQL help

\?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "as" in your query.
Select Id as id, username as username....

Comment: The 'as' works for me : `SELECT ar.invnumber as "Inv No", ar.amount as "Inv Total", ar.transdate as "Inv Date", customer.name as "Customer", acc_trans.amount as "Amount Recd", acc_trans.transdate as "Date Recd"`